# Android 6 BLE maximum connection interval

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use Android 6.0.1, Sumsung S6 with Dialog development board. To reduce power consumption, I'm trying to set the connection interval as large as possible. It works when changing the connection interval to 300ms, however, when I change it even larger the actual connection interval is 30ms. The maximum connection interval should be 4s according to BLE specs, and does Android have different specifications? Thanks.

Comment: What are your minimum and maximum connection intertval, your slave latency and supervision timeout values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your post on the DA14580 forum. It seems you have chosen 5 seconds for supervision timeout. But according to the BLE 4.1 standard the supervision timeout must be larger than 2*conn_intv_max. So if you have a connection interval of 4 seconds you need at least 8010 ms supervision timeout (note that the supervision timeout resolution is 10 ms). If you use slave latency you must set supervision timeout to something larger than 2*conn_intv*(sup_to+1).

Comment: Hi Emil, thanks so much for your answer! I found parameters constraints here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/technical-considerations and it seems that timeout >= conn_intv*(sup_to+1). However, even though I change the timeout to 8010ms or even more it still doesn't work. I don't know if Dialog has their own specs.

Comment: It seems their website has not been updated. In BT 4.0 those were the limitations, but since BT 4.1 a new multiply by 2 has been added. See the current BT 5.0 spec, Vol 6, Part B section 4.5.2. If it still doesn't work I'd suggest you look at the Bluetooth HCI snooplog generated by Android since there you can see the exact connection parameter update procedure and where it goes wrong.